# Leap Motion Custom Gestures

Tags: unity-game-engine, gesture, leap-motion

Is there any program that allows custom gestures recording and exporting?
Of course custom gestures for Leap Motion.

The pre-made gestures are not enough for me to make the app.

I tried this old system:
[LeapTrainer](https://github.com/roboleary/LeapTrainer.js/tree/master#importing-and-exporting-from-leaptrainer)

However, I have a problem on importing and exporting, and the data exported seems not useful out of LeapTrainer.

Update 1: I tried to find gadgets from Unity Asset Store, but to no avail. Can anyone suggest some tools/SDKs? My main purpose is to use gestures as dynamic slashing(vertically/horizontally/diagonally).

**Please anyone can help me?**

Comment: I haven't tried it, but this library looks promising: http://www.nickgillian.com/wiki/pmwiki.php?n=GRT.GestureRecognitionToolkit It is written in C++, so you would need to make a C# wrapper to use it in Unity, though.

Answer (score 1):

I started the same way as you did, but i end up building my own gestures base on the API outputs.
Its not that hard you just need to think it a bit.
For example working with fingers, isExtended and Angle between them helps alot.
For the palm you can use the GetPosition and where is pointing at.

So you can do if palm pointing to my face and the hand is open(base on fingers) you will mimic the ARM HMD menu that you see on the LM samples out there.

Or if IndexFinger is extended and the thumb draw a gun on your hand, if the thumb angle is < 10 make the gun shoot.

I truly recommend you to go that way, it will help to expand your knowledge on the device API. 3rd party tools might work but you need to learn how to use them, so better spend that time learning the LM API.